# getting updated data from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I am quite new to android developer, iam getting data from activity to fragment through bundle but bundle data is updated through menu option but fragment not getting updated data.

//Calling Fragment....

```
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        final Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        String sid=mStudents.get(selectedno).getStudentId();
        bundle.putString("studentidbundle", sid);
        // Toast.makeText(this, ""+sid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ProgressFrame progressFrame=new  ProgressFrame();
        progressFrame.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("FrameTransaction");
        fragmentTransaction.detach(progressFrame);
        fragmentTransaction.attach(progressFrame);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fraame1main, progressFrame);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

//Getting data from activity to fragment

```
        sid = getArguments().getString("studentidbundle");
```

Comment: show your codes

Comment: What have you done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create interface in Activity class

- Activity code

```
private FragmentRefresh fragmentRefresh;

public interface FragmentRefresh{
    void refresh(String data);
}

public void setFragmentListener(FragmentRefresh fr){
    this.fragmentRefresh = fr;
}

// call interface function where ever you required
    fragmentRefresh.refresh(data);
```

implement that interface in fragment

- Fragment code

```
((YourActivity)getActivity).setFragmentListener(new FragmentRefresh(){
    @Override
    public void refresh(String data){
        //use this data
    }
});
```

Maybe this code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
public static ProgressFrame getInstance(string id){
        ProgressFrame progressFrame=new  ProgressFrame();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("studentidbundle", id);
        progressFrame.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment ;
}
```

now you can use beginTransaction in this way :

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fraame1main, ProgressFrame.getInstance(sid));
```